Is the integral over a volume of $\operatorname{grad}(U) \cdot r$ always zero?
Let $r(x,y,z)=(x,y,z)$ and $U$ be any scalar field (continuously differentiable). Give an example where $$\int_{\Omega}\nabla U \cdot r \ \mathrm dV \neq 0$$ (or prove the integral is always zero) The answer by Andrew H. here on Physics SE suggests that this integral is always zero for bounded closed regions. I'm interested only in these types of regions of integration.

Just take $U=\frac{1}{2}\vec{r}.\vec{r}$. Then $\nabla U = \vec{r}$ and the integrand is therefore given by $\nabla U \cdot \vec{r} = \vec{r}.\vec{r}$. This is always positive except at the origin. As a result, the integral will be positive whenever $\Omega$ has nonzero measure.
